# CSS Hover will not work on Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, layout

Hey guys this is my second question so far on a website i'm re-designing for my boss. I'm trying have it where if the user hovers over "4-Color Offset Printing" the background of the div ID will change to another background-color. (Example blue). I've tried adding #4_color_offset_printing:hover to see if that will just simply change the background color. This usually works but on this navigation bar it seems to not be working. Right now the default background is green. I'd like it to turn blue when i hover over it. I'm trying to apply this affect to every link but if i could get one working i could figure out the rest.

The older style of the navigation bar is the Gray with the blue link hover affect. The last developer that designed the site decided to use inline CSS. I'm not a fan of inline, but even if i try to simply copy and paste his inline code to the main.css it does not take affect. I have no idea why that would be happening. If anybody has any advice that would be great!

Here is my [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/stinkytofu/akdz7udj/1/)

```
<style type="text/css"></style></head>

<body class="desktop webkit webkit_525">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="content_width rel">
            <a href="./Welcome to our site!_files/Welcome to our site!.html">
                <div id="header_logo"></div>
            </a>                

            <ul id="top_nav">
                <li><a class="home_icon" href="./Welcome to our site!_files/Welcome to our site!.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.offsetprinting.com/account/contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://secure.offsetprinting.com/account/estimate">Estimates</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.offsetprinting.com/helpcenter">Help Center</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://secure.offsetprinting.com/services/samples">Samples</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://secure.offsetprinting.com/account/summary">Shopping Cart</a></li>
                <li class="last-child"><a href="https://secure.offsetprinting.com/account/dashboard">My Account</a></li>
            </ul>

                            <ul id="loginbar" class="rounded">
                <li><a href="https://secure.offsetprinting.com/account/signup">New Account</a></li>
                <li class="last-child"><a href="https://secure.offsetprinting.com/account/login">Login</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="header_products"></div>                
                            <div id="header_phone">Customer Service: (949) 215-9060</div>               

            <div id="product_search">
                <input id="product_ti" class="default" type="text" value="Find A Product">
                <input id="product_btn" type="button" value="Search">
                <input id="product_default" type="hidden" value="Find A Product">
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="nav">
        <ul id="nav_links" class="content_width_adjust">

            <li id="4_color_offset_printing" style="width:183px; height:44px; background-color:#0C0; border-top: 4px solid #009ad6; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;" class=""><a class="nav_parent narrow" href=""><span>4-Color Offset Printing</span></a></li>

            <li id="large_format" style="width:139px" class=""><a class="nav_parent wide" href=""><span>Large Format</span></a></li>

            <li id="1-2_color_printing" style="width:164px"><a class="nav_parent" href=""><span>1&amp;2 Color Printing</span></a></li>

            <li id="4_color_digital_printing" style="width:189px"><a class="nav_parent narrow" href=""><span>4-Color Digital Printing</span></a></li>

            <li id="roll_labels" style="width:130px" class=""><a class="nav_parent wide" href=""><span>Roll Labels</span></a></li>

            <li id="services" class="last " style="width:133px"><a class="nav_parent services" href=""><span>Services</span></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elements ID can't start with a number, only classes can. Removing the 4_ from '4_color_offset_printing' so you just have a ID of 'color_offset_printing' will allow you to target it in CSS.

If you really don't want to change your ID's, you can target ID's that begin with a number like this:

```
[id='4_color_offset_printing'] {
background: blue;
}
```

But I wouldn't recommend using that, it may not work well in all browsers. Best to do things the right way and not use numbers to start your ID's.

Comment: Ahh. So that's why the last developer used inline styles to style the ones with numbers at the start. He must of not known that, and used the inline as a work around. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add to the #nav_links li a:hover class

```
#nav_links li a:hover
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/akdz7udj/7/